# Azure: WebMatrix not loading in Windows 10 Edge

Tags: windows, azure, azure-web-app-service, windows-10, webmatrix-3

I am having a few problems with azure at the moments. i have recently added the new Windows 10 OS to a laptop, and before on Windows 8.1 whenever we clicked one of our azure websites then WebMatrix, It would load up WebMatrix, Ever since we have moved to Windows 10, whenever i click onto Webmatrix through the azure platform, it doesn't load.

I also have tried logging into WebMatrix by loading the program from my computer and not azure, but i get an error saying 'Error to load azure websites.'

Thank you in advance - We want to migrate over to Windows 10, but cannot until we find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 is still installed with Windows 10. You can launch it from the start menu or from the More Actions menu (...) in Edge.